# Variable Assignment in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the end of my function, I have the statement:

```
RETURN @Result
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
IF (@Result = '')
BEGIN
@Result = 'Unknown'
END

RETURN @Result
```

The above does not work though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET @Result = 'Unknown'
```

;)

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (@Result = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT @Result = 'Unknown'
END

RETURN @Result
```

Notice that the way you do assignment in T-SQL is the `SELECT` statement. You can also use the `SET` statement although that is discouraged.

Comment: really? Why is SET discouraged?

Comment: SET is the command for setting options (SET ANSI_QUOTES ON, SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF). SELECT is the command for all queries,  and queries are more than capable of assigning values to variables (if there is only one row). You could use SET @myvar = (SELECT TOP 1 MyCol FROM MyTable), but what's the point when you could also do SELECT TOP 1 @myvar = MyCol, @myvar2 = MyCol2, @myvar3 = MyCol3 FROM MyTable.

Comment: It tends to be a religious thing, but for something like this where you're setting a local variable, both SELECT and SET are used and acceptable.

Justice, can you come up with an article that would back up the "discouraged" claim?

I generally use SET when it involves just one variable and SELECT when I'm setting multiple variables in a single command.

Answer (score 2):

change this line

```
@Result = 'Unknown'
```

to

```
set @Result = 'Unknown'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check if @result is NULL, because NULL is not the same as ''

```
IF (ISNULL(@Result, '') = '')
BEGIN
    SET @Result = 'Unknown'
END

RETURN @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

IF (@Result = '')

BEGIN

```
SET @Result = 'Unknown'
```

END

RETURN @Result

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @Result = 'Unknown'
```

@Justice: According to Microsoft - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) 
`SELECT @Result = 'Unknown'` is generaly discouraged